# How do i replace Numbers with letters using dictionaries in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have been developing an application to convert decimal numbers into hexadecimal ones. Whole software is done but the problem in i have to convert digits like "11", "12" into "B", "C".

For this, i made a dictionary but i don't know how to apply that into my software.

```
hexadecimal_value = {1: "1",
                     2: "2",
                     3: "3",
                     4: "4",
                     5: "5",
                     6: "6",
                     7: "7",
                     8: "8",
                     9: "9",
                     10: "A",
                     11: "B",
                     12: "C",
                     14: "D",
                     15: "E"}
while 1:
    print("we are about to convert decimal numbers into hexadecimal 
    numbers.")
    decision = input("type 'stop' to stop, type anything to Continue")
    if decision != "stop":
        try:
            h = int(input("Enter an integer\n>"))
        except ValueError:
            print("This is not an integer, silly!")
            h = int(input("Enter an integer\n>"))
        lup = 1
        hexadecimal_digits = []
        while lup == 1:
            hexa = h%16
            hexadecimal_digits.append(str(hexa))
            h = int(h/16)
            if h<1:
                lup = 2

    def Reverse_hexa(hexadecimal_digits):
        hexadecimal_digits.reverse()
        return hexadecimal_digits
    print("-".join(Reverse_hexa(hexadecimal_digits)))
if decision == "stop":
    input("close:")
    break
```

Comment: `hex(number)` will do that... see [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hex).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all because your dictionary uses int as keys, don't save the digits as strings, meaning: change the `append`ing line to:

```
hexadecimal_digits.append(hexa)
```

Now you just need to translate the digits to the symbols using your dictionary:

```py
hexadecimal_symbols = [hexadecimal_value[digit] for digit in hexadecimal_digits]
```

And now print those:

```
print("-".join(Reverse_hexa(hexadecimal_symbols)))
```

---

Alternatively, just save the translated symbols from the start:

```
hexadecimal_digits.append(hexadecimal_value[hexa])
```

And the rest stays the same

Comment: Can you mention the line number please? Its getting confusing as it shows KeyError:3 and i dont know where did it got worng

Comment: well, while testing your code I did notice you simply miss one character... 15 is actually `"F"` so look in your dictionary you are missing `13`. In general a KeyError means you're trying to get a key that is not in the dictionary, so that kinda gives you an idea where to look

Answer (score 0):

Just the following

```
hexadecimal_value[10]
```

Alternatively you don't need to declare a dictionary:

```
hex(10)
>>>'0xa'
```

and if you want just the capital letter:

```
hex(10).upper()[2:]
```

Comment: I did not understood perfectly

Comment: What did you not understand?